# Magento2: How to add Bundle Product in cart via REST API?

Tags: magento2, addtocart, rest-api, bundled-product

I need to add a bundle product in cart via **REST API**.

Is there any sample code by which I can pass only SKU code and bundle product will add into cart.

Please help me in this.

Comment: Hi, any news about this question? Did you find any solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In case you still need it.

Let's assume that our bundle is identified by the SKU "bundle01" and ID *123*.

First of all, let's take some information from the product:

`GET /products/bundle01?searchCriteria`

and take note of the `"extension_attributes" --> "bundle_product_options"` section, particularly to the `option_id`fields related to your products. And take not of all the `product_links` --> `id` values related to the product.

Let's assume that we have 3 products in the bundle, with option_id 643, 644, 645 and id 704,705,706 respectively.

With all these information, here's the body to add a bundle product to your cart:

```
{
"cart_item": {
    "quote_id": <quote_id>,
    "sku": "bundle-01",
    "qty": 1,
    "product_option": {
    "extension_attributes": {
        "bundle_options": [{
            "option_id": 643,
            "option_qty": 1,
            "option_selections": [704]
            }, {
            "option_id": 644,
            "option_qty": 1,
            "option_selections": [705]
            }, {
            "option_id": 645,
            "option_qty": 1,
            "option_selections": [706]
            }]
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: thank you, you do not understand the deep gratitude I have for you & this answer